# Carousel works fine in windows but gets stuck in android

Tags: python, android, kivy, carousel

My (Kivy) gui app has a carousel view in it, which works absolutely fine when i run the code on win10 and on ubunutu but whenever it is packed by buildozer to an apk file and i install it and then run it on my phone, the carousel gets stuck on the first slide and does not move left or right.(not even with the `load.next()` and `load.previous()` method)

Indside the `Carousel's` sildes the are `ScrollViews` and inside the scrollview there are `GridLayouts` and I think the problem is with the `GridLayout's` height. Because yesterday after a 16/17 rounds of trial&error, i changed something in the `GridLayout's` `row_default_height` and the `Carousel` worked (even in android) it moved left and right but the positon was not correct. While trying to fix the `Gridlayout's` `pos`, not only i couldn't fix it i also forgot the fix for the carousel.

here is my current py:

```
class NotSameButSimilar(Carousel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NotSameButSimilar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.pst_nt, 0)
        self.loop = True
        self.min_move = 1

    def refresh(self):
        self.pst_nt(None)
        refresh_pop()

    def pst_nt(self, dt):
        self.clear_widgets()
        dn.load()
        for k, v in dn.DND.items():    #dn is another class where data is imported from(json)
            self.upbarBL = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, .1),
                                     spacing=1,
                                     padding=1)
            self.mainkeylbl = DNVLabel(text=str(k),
                                       font_size='13sp',
                                       size_hint=(.85, 1))
            self.deltbtn = Button(text='X',
                                  font_size='14sp',
                                  background_color=(1, .2, 0, 1),
                                  size_hint=(.15, 1))
            self.deltbtn.bind(on_release=lambda *args, key=k: dn.delete_delivery_note(key))

            self.nextbtn = DNVButton(text='>',
                                     size_hint=(.2, 1),
                                     on_release=lambda x: self.load_next())
            self.backbtn = DNVButton(text='<',
                                     size_hint=(.175, 1),
                                     on_release=lambda x: self.load_previous())
            self.refrbtn = DNVButton(text='Frissit',
                                     size_hint=(.3, 1))
            self.refrbtn.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.refresh())
            self.bl1 = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, .08),
                                 padding=1,
                                 spacing=1)
            self.bl2 = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, .9))
            self.bl3 = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, .15),
                                 orientation='vertical',
                                 spacing=1,
                                 padding=1)

            #the problemtic stuff is here

            self.sc = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False,
                                 do_scroll_y=True,
                                 size_hint=(1, 1),
                                 pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0})
            self.scgl = GridLayout(row_force_default=True,
                                   row_default_height='30dp',
                                   cols=1,
                                   spacing=(3, 2))
            self.scgl.bind(minimum_height=self.scgl.setter('height'))


            # i have added all the widgets to their correct parent widgets
            # for abbreviation reasons i didnt include all the code(its too long)
```

*note: i know its a lot easier to use kivy rule but here i had to use python, though where ever i could use kivy, i did use kivy.(it makes life easier)